# If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ with $ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-a_0-a_1(x-x_0)}{x-x_0}=0$ prove that ...

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ and there are constants $a_0$ and $a_1$ s.t.
>   $$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-a_0-a_1(x-x_0)}{x-x_0}=0$$ 
>   then $a_0=f(x_0)$, $f'$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f'(x_0)=a_1$

'

From $-a_0-a_1(x-x_0)$, we can recognize a function in term of $x$: $$ A(x)=a_0+a_1(x-x_0)$$

As $x \rightarrow x_0$, we have an expression in the form $\frac{f(x)-A(x)}{x-x_0} \rightarrow 0$

.

$f$ is continuous, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) =f(x_0^-)=f(x_0^+)= f(x_0)$.
So, we can state that there exists a tangent of order one at $x_0$ on $f$ such that 
$$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-T(x)}{x-x_0}=0$$ where
$$ T(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)  (x-x_0)$$

.

It follows that $A(x) = T(x)$ where $a_0 =f^{(0)}$ and $a_1=f^{(1)}$

.
What would a more efficient approach be?

Any input is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one hand, 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\left[\frac{f(x)-a_{0}-a_{1}(x-x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}\right](x-x_{0})=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\left[\frac{f(x)-a_{0}-a_{1}(x-x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}\right]\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}(x-x_{0})=0\cdot0=0.
$$
On the other hand, for $x\neq x_{0},$ 
$$
\left[\frac{f(x)-a_{0}-a_{1}(x-x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}\right](x-x_{0})=f(x)-a_{0}-a_{1}(x-x_{0}).
$$
Letting $x\rightarrow x_{0}$, we have 
$$
0=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}f(x)-a_{0}-a_{1}\cdot0=f(x_{0})-a_{0}.
$$
 That is, $f(x_{0})=a_{0}$.

Now for $x\neq x_{0}$,
$$
\frac{f(x)-a_{0}-a_{1}(x-x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}=\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}-a_{1}.
$$
Rearranging terms, 
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}=a_{1}+\frac{f(x)-a_{0}-a_{1}(x-x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}.
$$
By assumption, the limit 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)-a_{0}-a_{1}(x-x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}
$$
 exists and is equal to 0, so the limit 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}
$$
 also exists and 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}=a_{1}+\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)-a_{0}-a_{1}(x-x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}=a_{1}+0=a_{1}.
$$
This shows that $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}$ and $f'(x_{0})=a_{1}$.

Comment: Thx for proof. Really impressive argumentation. Trying to understand from the original problem "if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$" where does this given information fall in the argumentation?

Comment: The given condition "$f$ is continuous at $x_0$" is used in "$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$".

Comment: Thx. one more question, how would you show that $f^{(1)}(x)$ is in turn differentiable (the original question)?

Comment: By definition, "$f$ is differentiable at the point $x_0$" means the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ exists. Moreover, such limit is denoted by $f'(x_0)$, called the derivative of $f$ at the point $x_0$.

Comment: I think there may be a typo in the original question. It should be "$f$ is differentiable" but not "$f'$ is differentiable". Otherwise, it is asking that $f$ is twice differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

Outline:

In order for the limit to exist the numerator must go to $0$. Noting the continuity of $f$, $a_0=f(x_0)$.

Then note that $\lim_{x \to x_0} a_1 \frac{ x-x_0}{x-x_0}= a_1$ and add this to both sides.

Conclude.

Comment: Thx for the input. Trying to follow your outline. difficult for me to understand. Could you elaborate on "noting the continuity of $f$, $a_0 =f(x_0)$?